# Divide and conquer algorithm that determines whether a candidate received a majority .

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Suppose  that  the  votes  of  $n$ people  for  different  candidates  $\left(\text{ where there can be more than two candidates } \right)$ for a particular  ofﬁce  are  the  elements  of  a  sequence . A person  wins  the  election  if  this  person  receives  a  majority  of  the votes.

Devise  a  divide and conquer  algorithm  that  determines  whether  a  candidate received  a  majority  and , if  so ,  determine who this candidate is.

My Approach --:

$\Rightarrow$ Divide the list into two half $\frac{n}{2}$  $\left ( \text{assuming }         n=2^{k}   \right)$

$\Rightarrow$ will last dividing list till we reach containg $2$ list .

$\Rightarrow$ we will have  **to**scan for all $n$ element to find the occurance  of  the majority one .

So recurrence relation looks like

$T \left( n \right)$ = $2*T \left(\frac{n}{2}  \right)$+$n$
 = $2^{k}*T \left(\frac{n}{2^{k}}  \right)$+$n$*$k$

Now terminating condition becmes when $T \left( \frac{n}{2^{k}} \right)$ = $1$

where     $\frac{n}{2^{k}} $=$2$  $\Rightarrow 2^{k} =\frac{n}{2} $

Coming back to my equation ,
$T \left( n \right)$ =  $2^{k}$+$n$*$k$  =$\frac{n}{2}$+n * $log_{2} \frac{n}{2}$

$\Theta  \left(n \right)$=$n*log _{2} \frac{n}{2}$

am i correct ??..add some points where i am wrong ..thank you !

Comment: please help someone

Comment: It seems to me that at worst the algorithm should be linear time: that would amount to literally summing up the votes and identifying the maximum. This takes linear time provided adding 1 to an integer takes constant time. So your algorithm seems harder than it should be. The more interesting question is whether you can use D&C to get an even faster algorithm.

Comment: @ lan :: can you add your idea ?

Comment: I don't have a better divide and conquer idea (my linear time suggestion is not of the divide and conquer type).

Comment: how can you solve the above algo in  linear time @ lan

Comment: Let's say you already know the collection of candidates; give each of them their own integer variable. Go through the list of votes and increment the appropriate variable at each step. The only difficulty is "finding" the right variable to increment, but that can be done using e.g. a hash table or (if the number of candidates is fixed) just if/else cases.